# How can I read a file which will be upload from a form in .Net Core API?

Tags: c#, file, upload, asp.net-core-webapi

I create a method in my .Net Core API which will upload a file.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ReadFile(IFormFile file)
{
    return BadRequest(file);
}
```

I do a `return BadRequest(file)` in order to read what it send me on **postman**.

The result is this :

```
{
    "contentDisposition": "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"data.dat\"",
    "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Disposition": [
            "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"data.dat\""
        ],
        "Content-Type": [
            "application/octet-stream"
        ]
    },
    "length": 200,
    "name": "file",
    "fileName": "data.dat"
```

}

I see on Microsoft documentation this :

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
{
    // Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
        String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

But the user will have to choose a file to read in it, the application won't have to go in a folder and read a file.

It is possible to do this ? And can I have some link to help me to do this ?

**Update**

I want to the method ReadFile read the content of my file which will be upload thinks to a form.

So I will have a string which will have the content of my file and after that I will can all I wanted to do in this file.

For example I have a file and in this file it is wrote **LESSON**, with the method **ReadFile** I will get the word lesson in a string.

Comment: I believe you should be more precise on what you would like to achieve exactly. Maybe it is just me, but I do not understand what you wanna know.

Comment: @Skrface it's update say it if it's style not understandable.

Comment: will u allow only txt files to be uploaded? not all files can be read like that

Comment: So, you want to read your IFormFile from your controller and extract the content as a string. Is that correct ?

Comment: @Skrface it's right.

Comment: @GeorgeHuman just .dat file so yes just text file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In you Controller :

1. Check if `IFormFile file` contains something
2. Check if the file's extension is the one you are looking for (.dat)
3. Check if the file's Mime type is correct to avoid attacks

Then, if it is all right, call a Service class to read your file.

In your Service, you can do something like following :

```
var result = new StringBuilder();
using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
{
    while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
        result.AppendLine(await reader.ReadLineAsync()); 
}
return result.ToString();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 21):

The file will be bound to your `IFormFile` param. You can access the stream via:

```
using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
{
    // do something with stream
}
```

If you want to read it as a string, you'll need an instance of `StreamReader`:

```
string fileContents;
using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    fileContents = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `StreamReader` and not `StringReader`?